# If $f$ is analytic in $D_r(z_0)-\{z_0\}$ and $\Re f(z)>0$ for all $z\in D_r(z_0)-\{z_0\}$, then $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f$ is analytic in a punctured disc $D_r(z_0)-\{z_0\}$ and we have $\Re f(z)>0$ for all $z\in D_r(z_0)-\{z_0\}$, then $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

I showed that $z_0$ cannot be an essential singularity of $f$. But I cannot figure out a way to show that $f$ doesn't have a pole at $z_0$. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: choose $g(z)$ such that $g(f(z))$ is bounded

Comment: $g(z)=e^{-z}$ makes $g(f(z))$ bounded. So $g$ must be analytic in the given disc (Riemann). But how to say that $f$ must be the same?

Comment: It may be easier to consider $T(f(z))$ with  $T(z) = (z-1)/(z+1)$ ...

Comment: Find a branch of $\log z$ holomorphic/analytic on an open around $z= e^{-f(0)}$

Comment: Doesn't the principal branch work?

Comment: let $h(z)$ some holomorphic logarithm of $g(z)$ i.e. $g(z)=e^{h(z)}$ then $f(z)=h(z)+2kπi$ where $k∈Z$ ($k$ is constant by continuity and connectedness) therefore $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $D(r,z0)$. This was taken from the post suggested by @MartinR. But I cannot understand how the final conclusion is made.

Comment: I have added another answer to that Q&A which does not require a logarithm.

Comment: I dont understand how to proceed. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Let's work in $U=\{0<|z|<1\}$ for convenience. Because $f$ maps to the right half plane, Casatori-Weierstrass shows $f$ does not have an essential singularity at $0.$ Thus $f$ has at worst a pole. Suppose, then, that

$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{z^k} +g(z)$$

in $U,$ where $a_n\ne 0$ and $g$ is analytic in the open unit disc. Write $a_n = |a_n|e^{it_0}.$ If we then look at $f(re^{it}),$ where $t = (t_0+\pi)/n,$ we find

$$f(re^{it}) = -\frac{|a_n|}{r^n} + O\left (\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\right )\, \, \text { as } r\to 0^+.$$

That implies $f(re^{it})$ has negative real part for small $r>0,$ contradiction. Thus $f$ has no pole at $0,$ and $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$ as desired.